# Can CSS :after contain content of this element?

Tags: css

Quick and simple question. Let's say I have this link: `<a href="">abc</a>`

Can I use `abc` as `content` of `a:after { content: ???; }` anyhow? I don't want to create additional `data-myattr`.

W3 says something like this:

> attr(X) This function returns as a string the value of attribute X for
>   the subject of the selector. The string is not parsed by the CSS
>   processor. If the subject of the selector does not have an attribute
>   X, an empty string is returned. The case-sensitivity of attribute
>   names depends on the document language.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content

Comment: No, not really. You could do `<a data-abc="abc" href="">abc</a>` and then use `content: attr('data-abc')`.

Comment: @Blender Ok, thanks! I'll do that if that's the only way.

Comment: Also, maybe( but probably won't work for what you might want to do) experiment with `text-shadow: 50px 0 0 black` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible, so it’s better to consider the original problem, for which this was an assumed solution.

In the [CSS3 Generated and Replaced Content Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/) draft, there is the possibility of using `content: contents` for an `:after` pseudo-element, but this would only work if this was the only use of the element’s content (you would have `content: none` for the real element), i.e. it is not meant for duplicating the content. Moreover, it’s a very outdated module, and most of its proposed novelties (including this) have no known implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can put strings into content:. This is the relevant documentation about it: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#strings

Comment: But you have to hardcode it into the CSS instead of taking it directly from the HTML element.